# Need specific regex for addresses

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this so far

```
\d{1,5}\ ?\d{0,5}\ ?[a-zA-Z]{1,10}\.?\ ?[a-zA-Z]{0,10}\.?\ ?[a-zA-Z]{1,30}\ ?[a-zA-Z]{2,30}\ ?[a-zA-Z]{2,30}\ ?[a-zA-Z]{0,15}\,?\s?
```

I am by no means an expert, but i got this far and it works really well.  the only thing is that it keeps picking up the same error when it comes through.  This one:

```
1805 is available to be downloaded from
```

Is there a way to block this specific string?  It is the same phrase exactly every time.  Otherwise it works like charm.  I can settle for removing any key word as well.

Really appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Josh

Comment: That's pretty lengthy. There's probably a way to simplify it, which would probably be a better approach than adding an exclusion rule.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and expected output, and possibly describe what you mean by "addresses"?

Comment: Maybe set a blacklist containing _"download"_ and/or _"available"_, then it would fail before your regex evaluation, just an idea.

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: Tool is this one https://regexr.com/

Comment: how can i blacklist?  That sounds perfect